# Why did we get so much XP in this dungeon?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I'm of course not asking for anyone to go dig into the game logs to figure out **exactly** why we got so much XP but here is the situation.

My friend and I decided to do a dungeon, we're both level 50 at this point, my friend in the low 20's of champion points and me in the 120's.

This is the first dungeon we're playing, I think, whatsoever. We queue up using the dungeon finder for a random *normal* dungeon. We ended up going through [Blackheart Haven](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Blackheart_Haven).

When we complete the dungeon my friend gained about 18-20 champion points and I gained 7-8 of them.

We've not been able to reproduce this XP gain afterwards.

We've thought about:

- Perhaps this was the first dungeon that day, so the daily bonus was the source
- Perhaps we had both the "enlightened" bonus and our 50% xp bonus scrolls going

We've done other dungeons in the days afterwards, both as the "first dungeon that day" as well as having the aforementioned bonus XP going. Neither have given us anything close to that amount of XP, it's more like I get 1 champion point and my friend gets 2-3.

The dungeon we did that first day, could it be that it gives that much more XP than other dungeons?

Comment: Which dungeon it is would be helpful

Comment: Just found it, it was Blackheart Haven, will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyday, having two first runs in dungeons using the Dungeon Finder gives bonus XP.

The first run will give tons of bonus XP and a purple item in your mailbox.
The second run will give you a bit more XP than normal and a blue item in your mailbox.

The third run, or any without using the dungeon finder will not give you any additional XP or items in the mailbox.

Comment: When does this part reset? I notice for instance that my hirelings comes all willy nilly as I play so I guess these comes on 24-hour intervals from when I unlocked the skill, are the dungeons on the similar timer? Ie. if I take a pause for a week now just to reset the timers and then do a dungeon at 19:00 hours, will my next "first dungeon" be after 19:00 the next day, or does it reset on a more stable fixed time?

Comment: I found information on a [forum](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/719738-the-elder-scrolls-online-tamriel-unlimited/73556847) that it is reseted exactly 24 hours after you finish your last run.

Comment: OK, so if I start a dungeon run at 19:00 today, and finish it 19:30 today, my next "first of the day" dungeon will be after 19:30 tomorrow?

Comment: Side-question: Is it possible to see these timers somewhere? Many MMORPG games have "raid lockout timers", this sounds similar so perhaps there is a timer somewhere I can see it? I'm on console btw, Xbox One, so anything available through the API and thus an addon won't really help me.

Comment: I believe that it is visible on Dungeon Finder screen, not as a timer, but a message. If XP bonus is not yet available/was already used for the day - it should state that in the Dungeon Finder window. I can't check now though in the game.